# Laravel package/service provider addition

Tags: laravel, package, composer-php, service-provider

I'm trying to use https://github.com/sebdesign/laravel-state-machine in my laravel application. But the package is not installed correctly. My controller doesn't recognise it. 
First, I added the following to my composer.json

```
"repositories": [
  {
     "type": "vcs",
     "url": "https://github.com/sebdesign/state-machine"
  }
]
```

Then I run

```
composer require sebdesign/laravel-state-machine:1.0
```

Then I added the following in my config/app.php

```
'providers' => [
    Sebdesign\SM\ServiceProvider::class,
],

'aliases' => [
    'StateMachine' => Sebdesign\SM\Facade::class,
],
```

After that I Publish the config file in config/state-machine.php using

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Sebdesign\SM\ServiceProvider"
```

And that was it. Now I'm trying to use it in my controllers as:

```
// Using the facade
$stateMachine = StateMachine::get($article, 'simple');
```

But **StateMachine** is not recognised. I'm getting

```
Undefined type 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\Resource\StateMachine'
```

Am I missing something here? Should i add a *use* statement for something in the beginning of my controller?

Edit: Laravel 5.1
Thanks

Comment: Looks like you haven't included a `use` statement. Please check your code accordingly, and remove the tags that are not relevant

Comment: Yeah that's my question, what should i include as a use statement. Can you write it down please

Comment: Yeah i just figure it out. I added the use \SM\Factory\Factory as SMFactory; to my model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use following lines if you are using latest version and auto discovery tool.

> Since version 5.5, Laravel uses package auto-discovery, so you don't
>   need to manually add the ServiceProvider and the facade. If you don't
>   use auto-discovery or you are using an older version, add the service
>   provider and the facade in config/app.php.

```
<?php

'providers' => [
    Sebdesign\SM\ServiceProvider::class,
],

'aliases' => [
    'StateMachine' => Sebdesign\SM\Facade::class,
],
```

After composer require you need to directly run this command.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Sebdesign\SM\ServiceProvider"
```

You need to install compatible version of the package as per your laravel version.

```
composer require sebdesign/laravel-state-machine:^1.0
```

Then you need to use it as below:

```
use \SM\Factory\Factory as SMFactory;
```

Comment: @marmahan i have updated my answer pls. have a look for how to install your compatible version of the package.

Comment: @marmahan you need to follow all steps again with specific version of package.

Comment: Please explain further how this code resolves the given error message `Undefined type 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\Resource\StateMachine'`

Comment: It is working now. Thank you.  I reinstalled the package and added use \SM\Factory\Factory as SMFactory; to my model. And then i was able to call SMFactory

Comment: sure, I just did. But it would be a full answer if you could add to it the use statement
 use \SM\Factory\Factory as SMFactory;